# Combining bitmaps and resizing the result

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, android-canvas

I want to combine several smaller tiles/bitmaps into one large bitmap, resize it and then draw it on my canvas.

How should I go about this?

Comment: A canvas is nothing more than a holder for drawing calls.  Draw the individual bitmaps on the canvas in the right size and position, then the backing bitmap of the View will have the complete bitmap.

Comment: I see, but I still need to resize the final bitmap so that it fits my device screen exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Method for scaling the Bitmap

```
public Bitmap getImage (int id, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), id );
    Bitmap img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bmp, width, height, true );
    bmp.recycle();
    return img;
}
```

Scale the bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = getImage(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_HERE, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Draw the bitmap on your canvas at (x,y) (for more info about Paint click [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html))

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, paint);
```